# Is there a way to cancel a Mirth Channel destination file writer?

Tags: mirth

Is there a way to cancel a Mirth Channel destination file writer when no data has been returned.  I do not want to create a file each time the channel is run.  The channel need to run every 2-5 mins to process any pending records in the queue located in sql server.

I am using a Mirth channel to query a sql server database and output the data as a CSV file.  I am using Mirth Connect Server 3.2.0.7628.

Here is my script on the destination transformer.
I've tried to skip adding to tmp if result.Size() is not greater then zero.
Could not find this use case in the Mirth Connect documentation.

```
var dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xx:1433/<dbname>',<user>,<password>);

var result1 = dbConn.executeCachedQuery("exec [z_stored_procedure] param1");

var i = 0;  
if (result1.size()>0)   
{   logger.debug(result1.size())
    while(result1.next())
    {        
          tmp.row += <row>
           <DataField1>"{result1.getString('DataField1')}"</DataField1>
           <DataField2>"{result1.getString('DataField2')}"</DataField2>                                            
          </row>; 
      } 
}
```

dbConn.close();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work to put your code in the Destination *Filter* rather than the *Transformer*.

After your if statement, add an:

```
else {
return false;
}
```

If you have data it will run your transformation and pass it to the Destination.
If you don't it will filter the message and do nothing to the Destination.

Answer (score 1):

You can always exclude that destination from processing the message.

> For instance if a channel has many destinations and each message only needs to be processed by a single destination, by calling destinationSet.removeAllExcept(connectorName) in the source transformer, only that destination will receive the message. Those destinations will have no data stored and will not show up in the Message Browser. This is an alternative to filtering on each destination and can save processing time and disk space.

Comment: I know this is old but I've wasted a bit of time trying to get this to work and the cause was fast reading :). So, if anyone can't get this to work, pay attention to the fact that destinationSet is only available in the SOURCE transformer! I was in a hurry and trying to chain the destinations, making the first one in the chain decide which one should run. Of course that doesn't make sense when you have time to actually learn more about the feature and understand it, but there you go.